# How to click on the first email from gmail inbox in Seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gmail, seleniumbase

I was trying to get id from html in order to pass it like xpath, but this id is not the same like in chrome

[image: table of two emails in gmail]

absolute path is not suitable as it will always be different. Help please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there is only one `<table>` element with the following xpath and that specific element happens to be the one holding all the email elements:

```
//table[@role='grid']
```

So to click the first element I would use the following xpath:

```
//table[@role='grid']//tr[1]
```

There might be an issue depending on where exactly in the row the click will happen, but I doubt that it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The first email link in gmail has this selector:

```
'table td div[role="link"]'
```

To click it with SeleniumBase using the expanded `driver` format, use:

```py
driver.click('table td div[role="link"]')
```

To verify that the selector is valid from the Chrome Devtools console, use:

```js
document.querySelector('table td div[role="link"]')
```

Comment: I found this
driver.click('tr.zA.zE[role="row"]:nth-of-type(1)')
but it's not good maybe, because class could change